# 8 different tags for scraping webpages need synonymising

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I believe all of these tags should be synonyms.

Comments?

> [scrape](/questions/tagged/scrape) 326
>
> [scraper](/questions/tagged/scraper) 185
>
> [scraping](/questions/tagged/scraping) *synonym*
>
> [screen-scraper](/questions/tagged/screen-scraper) 29
>
> [screen-scraping](/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) 1,648
>
> [web-scraping](/questions/tagged/web-scraping) 1,972
>
> [webpagescraping](/questions/tagged/webpagescraping) 29
>
> [webscraping](/questions/tagged/webscraping) *synonym*

Comment: Not to forget [scrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrapping).

Comment: I wouldn't say that screen scraping is synonymous (or should be) with web scraping.

Comment: @JonClements From the tag-wiki for *screen-scraping*: `Screen-scraping, also known as web-scraping`

Comment: @DannyBeckett: The tag wiki is incorrect.  Webpage scraping is very much different than screen scraping.

Comment: I agree about `scrape`,`scraper`, `scrapist` and `scrapping` (and maybe `scrapper` and...).

Comment: This synonym-request is from before the MSO-MSE split and is about Stack Overflow. The only tag on MSE is [screen-scraping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) and the synonyms page has no variations of it.